# Log4net file not created in Program Files

Tags: c#, winforms, log4net, installation-package

I have a windows application that uses `Log4net` for all Debug log.  This has been working fine in local machine. The log folder/files are created in `Debug / Release` folders appropriately.

I prepared installation package and installed on an end user machine.  Apparently, the software was installed in `Program Files (x86)` folder.  Application is working fine and it is creating business log files in other folders.  But, debug log is never created inside Application installation folder in Program Files.

- How do I ensure the file is created there?
- Is it an Admin task to provide users the read/write access to that folder? Or
- Do I need to change path of Debug logs from Program Files to some other folder where every user may have access?

My config is below

```
<log4net>
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Logs\Log_%date{MMddyyyy}.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] – %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
</root>
<logger>
  <level />
  <appender-ref />
</logger>
```

I have reviewed the answer in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376046/log4net-will-not-create-logfile-on-windows-7) but it didn't solve my problem.  I changed my path to `${ALLUSERSPROFILE}\Logs\Log_%date{MMddyyyy}.log` and the log file didn't show up anywhere

Comment: If you try to search, you'll see that the program files directories are for that: **program** files, or binaries and assets. Normal users and applications shouldn't write there. Indeed, write your logs to a directory writable by that user, for example AppData.

Comment: `Do I need to change path of Debug logs from Program Files to some other folder where every user may have access?` - Correct.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I have visited the link you marked as duplicate but it didn't create log file.  Please refer my updated question and remove duplicate marking so as to get working answer for me .  thanks

Comment: @Igor - Is there any general way to configure log path in App.config? may be something like setting path {user}\Appdata\logs\file.log

Comment: @techspider - absolutely. You can use `${USERPROFILE}`, `${LOCALAPPDATA}`, or `${APPDATA}`. See this [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3735675/1260204).

Comment: According to your edit, your logs should show up in `C:\ProgramData\Logs`. Look; all log4net questions have been asked before, try searching a bit. Create a directory like `C:\TempLog`, give all users full access and see if it logs there. [Enable log4net internal debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618380/log4net-does-not-write-the-log-file). Start ProcMon to see where it tries to write the log file. And so on.

Comment: thanks to both of your for your replies